# Trigger to delete table and then insert value with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How could i do a query with php and mysqli, to remove an entire table and then add new I have a form where data is received, but before adding the new data, I want to remove all data from table.
$oConni is my connection string

```
 $cSQLt  = "TRUNCATE TABLE approved";
$cSQLi = "INSERT INTO approved (ID_STUDENT, YEAR, APPROVED)
              VALUES (
              '" . $_POST['NSTUDENT'] . "',
                  '" . $_POST['YEAR'] . "',
                      'YES'
                                       )";

$oConni->query($cSQLt);
$oConni->query($cSQLi);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TRUNCATE TABLE and then your next query:

```
$cSQLt = "TRUNCATE TABLE CALIFICA_APTO";
$cSQLi = "INSERT INTO approved (ID_STUDENT, YEAR, APPROVED)
          VALUES (
          '" . $_POST['NSTUDENT'] . "',
              '" . $_POST['YEAR'] . "',
                  'YES'
                                   )";
$Connect->query($cSQLt);
$Connect->query($cSQLi);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove everything from a table with MySQL by issuing a TRUNCATE statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE approved;
```

.. which usually is the same as

```
DELETE FROM approved;
```

.. but there are a few small differences, which [you can read about in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html).

In the code you've pasted, please [use prepared statements](http://no.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid a sql injection attack. Never use unfiltered POST-data directly in a query!

If you want to do this as a trigger, we'll need to know a bit more about your data handling. Issuing a TRUNCATE before a INSERT will usually lead to only one row being available in the table, which seems like a weird use case for actually using a table.

Comment: Why not? Do you get any error messages? What did you try? You'll have to say something useful if you want help with what you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to remove all of the data from a table you should use [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html):

`TRUNCATE TABLE approved`

Then you can do your SQL statement.

**NOTE:** This will delete all data from the table, so **be careful**! Also, your database user must have the ability to truncate tables.